# Owl carousel 100% height

Tags: javascript, slider, height, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have a little problem with owl carousel 2,

This is the old version of my site, http://lukaszradwan.com/pl/
please take a look at the main slider. This is not owl carousel, I don't know what it is but it works fine (height is set to 100%) - and it's too heavy.

I have changed it to owl carousel, see this http://lukaszradwan.com/
It's responsive but I can't set height to 100%.

JS

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
items:1,
margin:0,
loop:true,
nav:true
});
```

HTML

```
      <div class="slider_container">
      <div class="owl-carousel">
<div class="item"><img src="img/banners/slajd.jpg" alt="The Last of us">   </div>

<div class="item"><img src="img/banners/slajd.jpg" alt="The Last of us"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="img/banners/slajd.jpg" alt="The Last of us"></div>




      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If You have any ideas how to do this, please share with me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure ? I can see both identical, no differences

Comment: Please resize your browser.

Comment: Already done, after resize the browser the carousel correctly resize (I'm using Chrome)

Comment: I am using Chrome as well, but see this: lukaszradwan.com/screen.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I solved the 100% height problem on mobile with css.
I know this is not the best solution but it works so far ...

```
.header-carousel.owl-carousel.owl-theme.owl-loaded.owl-drag,
.header-carousel .owl-stage-outer,
.header-carousel .owl-stage,
.header-carousel .owl-item,
.header-carousel .item,
.header-carousel .owl-item,
.header-carousel .img-responsive{
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```