# Owl carousel full screen doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, height, carousel, fullscreen

I am trying to make owl carousel slider full screen for my site.
This is what I need, feel free to resize Your browser

And this is what I have,

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zWbqV/57/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // carousel setup
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    navigation : false,
    slideSpeed : 300,
    paginationSpeed : 400,
    singleItem: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    afterMove: top_align,
  });

  function top_align() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
    console.log('move');
  }

});
```

is there any solution to fix it?

Thx

Comment: Isn't this the same question as - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629780/owl-carousel-100-height

Comment: No, the current version of owl carousel is 1.33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
} 

.owl-wrapper-outer {
    height: 100% !important;    
}

.owl-wrapper {
     height: 100%;   
}

.owl-item {
    height: 100%;
}

.b-Amarelo {
    height: 100%;
}

.owl-item h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zWbqV/59/)

Answer (score 1):

When using % for heights, you have to work your way down the DOM chain to your child element for the height to apply.

Another option is to take advantage of vh units. 100vh = 100% of the window height.

Just add 100vh to .owl-item and your div item.

```
.owl-item, .item {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

A `vh` unit [is defined as](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length):

> Equal to 1% of the height of the viewport's initial containing block.